# Custom service filling up syslog

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, syslog

We have a custom service we start via `systemd`. File is stored at `/etc/systemd/system/custom.service`.

That's all great but we just had a situation where the disk ran full. I guess `systemd` catches all of the process' `stdout` and writes it into `/var/log/syslog`.

Our custom service writes all of `STDOUT` into actual log files. So we could ignore `syslog`.

How can I suppress everything from `stdout` being written to `syslog`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in the [documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#StandardOutput=), you can redirect `StandardOutput=` to wherever you wish. By default this is `journal`. You can change it to `null` instead, to cause standard output to be discarded.

```
[Service]
StandardOutput=null
```

Comment: Awesome. Why was I not able to find it here: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html? I searched for "Standard" and no results

Comment: @transient_loop Because, as it says, only options unique to service units are documented there, and the common options are in other doc pages. "Service files must include a [Service] section, which carries information about the service and the process it supervises. A number of options that may be used in this section are shared with other unit types. These options are documented in systemd.exec(5), systemd.kill(5) and systemd.resource-control(5)."

Comment: Thanks. In the hurry to get our system back up I did not read everything well.